# Flutter- How can i handle (onPause/OnResume, onStart and OnTerminate) funactionality on flutter using firebase cloud messeging and notifications?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

#### firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0

#### flutter sdk 2.0.1

I am getting the message notification only when the app is running on background but not for terminate or on process app.

And getting the message `A background message could not be handled in Dart as no onBackgroundMessage handler has been registered.`

How to handle three functionality `(app is running already, app is running on backgroud, app is terminated)` into app using the latest version of cloud messegning library?

Here is the code that i have tried to implement.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage message) {

      print('I am called 1');
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;

      print('I am called 2');
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

     print('I am called 3');
    });
  }
```